# Credentials are required to create a Client on Twilio Laravel

Tags: laravel, twilio

I have a problem on last step on my input for my notification whatsapp , i search on this stackoverflow but i didnt find a solution for this .

i set .env and service like that

.env

```
TWILIO_AUTH_SID=ACaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN=09fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
TWILIO_WHATSAPP_FROM=+141xxxxxxx
```

my service

```
'twilio' => [
  'sid' => env('ACaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),
  'token' => env('09fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),
  'whatsapp_from' => env('+141xxxxxxx')
],
```

i dont know where my error if this error says " Twilio\Exceptions\ConfigurationException
Credentials are required to create a Client "

can someone have solution for this ? or someone have experience for this error ?

i following this tutorial [link](https://www.twilio.com/blog/create-laravel-php-notification-channel-whatsapp-twilio)

Comment: Can you share the code you are using to initialise the Twilio REST client?

Answer (score 2):

The env helper expects a string, which is supposed to be the key of the value you are trying to fetch from the .env file:

```
'twilio' => [
    'sid' => env('TWILIO_AUTH_SID'),
    'token' => env('TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN'),
    'whatsapp_from' => env('TWILIO_WHATSAPP_FROM')
],
```

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/configuration#retrieving-environment-configuration